# Will the files of other drives be deleted when formatting a dual-boot machine

Tags: windows-7, linux, hard-drive, multi-boot, formatting

I use both Windows and Linux on my computer by dual-booting. I also have 3 drives. On one I have Windows, on the other there is Linux and on the third one are my files (documents, pictures etc.). Now, I want to install a newer version of Linux overwriting the old one. Can I install it inside the drive where I have my old Linux? Will this installation harm the two other drives? Is there any thing I need to be careful to when doing the formatting?

Comment: Why would installing an operating system on Disk B effect any other disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make sure that you're selecting the correct drive. The formatting process will only touch the disks that you tell it to format.

As long as you select the Linux drive, your other drives will be left alone.

If you're especially nervous about doing this, just temporarily **disconnect** the other drives while you upgrade your Linux install.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few points to consider here. The short answer is, **files on other drives will be untouched as long as you don't select those drives to be formatted**.

**However**, you'll want to be conscious of the location of your bootloader. If you format the drive/partition with the bootloader, you may wind up borking your dual-boot setup.